# selenium Promise { <pending> } while expecting a string to be returned

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, promise

I am having issues with selenium.  I have output a modal that is popping up with a string from a submitted request.  I am looking to use findElement to grab that data using the xpath, and return the string to the console.  It looks like the promise is not resolved, and I'm not sure how to wrap this in a promise so I get the result of that promise.

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60822/devtools/browser/a2114051-85ec-47d7-9d62-9f9809ef732c

Test passed

Forms

Promise { < Pending> }

```
   var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

USERNAME = 'XXXXXX';
PASSWORD = 'XXXXXXXX';
WEBSITE = 'https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/';
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();
//tag[text()=’text value‘]


driver.get(WEBSITE);


driver.sleep(4000).then(function() {
    driver.findElement(By.id('username')).sendKeys(USERNAME);
    driver.findElement(By.id('password')).sendKeys(PASSWORD);
    driver.findElement(By.id('submit1')).click();
});


driver.sleep(26000).then(function() {
    driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
        if (title === 'Forms') {
            console.log('Test passed');
            console.log(title);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text() = 'Request']")).click();
            //driver.findElement(By.id('market')).selectBuyValue('CI').click();
            //*[@id="request"]/div[3]/div/input
            driver.sleep(4000).then(function() {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='market']")).sendKeys("CI");
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='request']/div[3]/div/input")).click();
            });
            driver.sleep(10000).then(function() {

                console.log(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='myModal']/div/div/div[1]/div")).getText());

                //THIS WORKS driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='myModal']/div/div/div[2]/button")).click();
            });


        } else {
            console.log(title);
            console.log('took to long');
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `driver.findElement()` and `WebElement.getText()` methods return a promise, so you will have to either `await` the call in an `async` function - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function - or increase your callback hell by calling the `then()` method like you do with the other promise instances.